# How mass update data on django db table?

Tags: django, django-models

I need often parse big xml file and insert and update data to db table. How I can do it fast without delete data from database. Now I delete all data before parse and insert all data after. But it way broke all foreign keys.

```
    for category in self.root.findall('.//categories/category'):
        try:
            cat_id = category.get('id')
            cat = CategoryModel(
                id=cat_id, name=category.text,
                picture=category.get('picture')
            )
            categories[cat_id] = cat

    CategoryModel.objects.all().delete()
    CategoryModel.objects.bulk_create(categories.values(), batch_size=50000)
```

Next my code generation. I use bulk_update:

```
    all_categories = CategoryModel.objects.all()
    created_categories = [str(cat[0]) for cat in all_categories.values_list('id')]
    new_cats = []
    update_cats = []
    for category in self.root.findall('.//categories/category'):
        try:
            cat_id = category.get('id')
            cat = CategoryModel(
                id=cat_id, name=category.text,
                picture=category.get('picture')
            )
            categories[cat_id] = cat

        if cat_id in created_categories:
            update_cats.append(cat)
        else:
            new_cats.append(cat)

    CategoryModel.objects.bulk_create(new_cats, batch_size=50000)
    all_categories.bulk_update(update_cats, fields=['name', 'picture'], batch_size=1000)
```

It code work. But may be you know better way?

Comment: Can i know which database you are using? Is it postgres?

Comment: @SrijwalR I use MySQL

Comment: I was using postgres. In a similar situation, i used db management studio like pgadmin to import data from excel to db. There are other db management studios like azure for mysql

Comment: @SrijwalR No, it no my way. I need every day automatic fill database using only django.

Comment: in that case, go with bulk_create